# Access-Control-Allow-Credentials problems React

Tags: reactjs, flask, cors, flask-cors

Here is a project to create a login system using react. However when it connects to the back-end flask to check whether the login is valid or not, it shows the error message below. Hope someone can help me. I spent so many days trying to fix this and search every related post but still couldn't fix it :(

I'm using the chrome browser.
Also, I have installed the Access-Control-Allow-Origin plugin on chrome.

error message

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

front-end code (react)

```
fetch(domain+"/login", {
    body: JSON.stringify(mydata),
    credentials: "include",
    headers: new Headers({
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
    }),
            
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrer: 'no-referrer', // *client, no-referrer
    })
    .then(response=>{
      
       if(response.ok){
            
         return response.json()
       }
     }
```

back-end(flask) include below code to allow cross origin

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
```

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    
    data = request.json       
    print(data)
    result = {}

    login_info = {
        "code": -1,
        "message": ""
    }
    
    if data:
        
        username = data['username']
        password = data['password']
        cur = database.cursor(dictionary=True)
        cur.execute(
            "SELECT username, password, role FROM user WHERE username = %s AND password = %s AND disabled = 0;", (username, password))
        # cur.execute("SELECT uid, displayname, rank, disabled FROM user WHERE username = %s AND password = %s;", (username, password,))
        # cur.execute("SELECT uid, displayname, rank, disabled FROM user WHERE username = %s AND password = AES_ENCRYPT(%s, UNHEX(SHA2('encryption_key', )));", (username, password,))
        account = cur.fetchone()
        if account:
            # modify_info(1, "Login successfully!")
            login_info["code"] = 1
            login_info["message"] = "Login successfully!"
            account_str = json.dumps(account, cls=MyEncoder)
            account_json = json.loads(account_str)
            session["username"] = account_json["username"]
            result["username"] = username
            result["role"] = account_json["role"]
            result["isLogin"] = 1

        else:
            # modify_info(0, "Login not successful")
            login_info["code"] = 0
            login_info["message"] = "Login not successful"

        cur.close()
    return jsonify({"code": login_info["code"], "data": result, "message": login_info["message"]})
```

Answer (score 1):

In the specification, the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header is not allowed to use with
the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header.

However, `*` is the default value for the origin header in flask cors, you should set it to a specific value, for example:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins=['http://localhost:3000'], supports_credentials=True)
```

Also, here is link to the document about it: https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

[image]

### Update

It seems like the `samesite` of the cookie problem, here's the code to set it:

```py
from flask import Flask, make_response
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)

@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def index():
    res = make_response()
    res.set_cookie("name", value="I am cookie", samesite='Lax')
    return res, 500

app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have changed the code to the above code but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Try disable the plugin maybe, and what's the `samesite` property of your cookie?

Comment: When turning off the plugin, it shows this error message.                        
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: what's samesite?

Comment: Tha's an attribute of the cookie, if it's `strict`, the browser will only store it if it's from the same origin. If it's `Lax`, then it's allowed to be from a different origin, but only with a 
 POST request. Check here for more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

Comment: I manage to reproduce the error message you have with your code. It seems like when your `/login` handler function raises an error before its returns, the cors header in response won't send back, and the corresponding `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present` error will raise. Maybe add a `try-except` block in your function to catch the error.

Comment: i add it and it shows: TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Do you mean the `samesite` of cookie? it should be set on the backend. Also, check if the backend raises an error first, I think that's the root cause of the problem.

Comment: i mean i add try catch block in the front-end and the error is type error.there's no response in backend.

Comment: The try-catch block should be added in the backend, for there is an exception in backend,  cause the cors header not return correctly

Comment: but backend doesn't show the post request method which means it doesn't come into the login api.

Comment: May I check some more parts of the backend code, without the sensitive part?

Comment: hi i have update the post

Comment: That's weird, is there any other middleware you use except for CORS? These code works fine with me

Comment: i'm using macbook, and it works on windows. Not sure the reason

Comment: hi i think the problem is the samesite property. could you provide the code for samesite property to set in the back end thanks. i change to another browser which is firefox and the error is Cookie “session” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute set to “None”

Comment: ```
from flask import Flask, make_response
res = make_response()
res.set_cookie("name", value="I am cookie", samesite='None')
return res, 200
```

Comment: before app = Flask(__name__)?

Comment: No, in the handler

Comment: i don't get it. where is the handler?

Comment: can you modify the post and show me sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243141/discussion-between-zheng-bowen-and-yan-skywalker).